# Cannot implicitly convert type system linq IQueryable to system collections generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

Unable to fetch Data from View Model  Controller to View,i have properly checked the working of query in LINQpad. However I am missing the conversion of the output of query which can be displayable in View.

I have three Data Models Products,Images,Specifications which i combined into ViewModel with only selected properties and want to displaythe same.

```
 public class ViewModelController : Controller
    {
        private OMSEntities db = new OMSEntities();
        // GET: ViewModel
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var product = new Product();
            var prices = new Price();
            var orders = new Order();
           ProductRegistrationViewModelVM  vm = new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM();

           vm =(from p in db.Products
                       join i in db.Images on p.ProductId equals i.Product_Id
                       join s in db.Specifications on p.ProductId equals s.Product_Id
                       select new
                       {
                           //Product
                           p.Name,
                           p.Produt_Code,
                           p.Description,
                           //Image
                           i.Image_Description,
                           i.Image_Name,
                           i.image1,
                           //Specifications
                           s.Sz_Measurement_Unit,
                           s.Size,
                           s.Wg_Measurement_Unit,
                           s.Weight,
                           s.Price_Set,
                           s.Price_Sold
                       });

          vm.Add(new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM());

            return View(vm.ToList());
        }
```

ViewModel Class

```
 public class ProductRegistrationViewModelVM
    {
        //Products
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Produt_Code { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Supplier_Id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Supplier> Supplier { get; set; }
        //Image
        public string Image_Description { get; set; }
        public string Image_Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] image1 { get; set; }

        //Specifications

        public string Sz_Measurement_Unit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Size { get; set; }
        public string Size_Name { get; set; }
        public string Wg_Measurement_Unit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Weight { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> Price_Set { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Price_Sold { get; set; }


    }
```

**Note:** I did look into the same error Questions in stack overflow However was not able to figure it out.

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string Name, string Produt_Code, string Description, string Image_Description, string Image_Name, byte[] image1, string Sz_Measurement_Unit, decimal? Size, string Wg_Measurement_Unit, decimal? Weight, int? Price_Set, int? Price_Sold>>' to 'OMS.ViewModels.ProductRegistrationViewModelVM'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

**Fix:**

As Suggested Below ProductRegistrationViewModelVM is made as List item and also ViewModel properties were bound to query properties.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var product = new Product();
            var prices = new Price();
            var orders = new Order();
            List<ProductRegistrationViewModelVM> vm = new List<ProductRegistrationViewModelVM>();
           vm= (from p in db.Products
                        join i in db.Images on p.ProductId equals i.Product_Id
                        join s in db.Specifications on p.ProductId equals s.Product_Id
                        select new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM()
                   {
                       //Product
                       Name=p.Name,
                       Produt_Code=   p.Produt_Code,
                       Description = p.Description,
                            //Image
                            Image_Description=  i.Image_Description,
                            Image_Name= i.Image_Name,
                            image1= i.image1,
                       //Specifications
                       Sz_Measurement_Unit= s.Sz_Measurement_Unit,
                            Size= s.Size,
                            Wg_Measurement_Unit=s.Wg_Measurement_Unit,
                            Weight=s.Weight,
                            Price_Set=s.Price_Set,
                            Price_Sold= s.Price_Sold
                   }).ToList();

            return View(vm);
        }
```

Comment: You need to show the full details of the error in your question. Your query creates a collection of anonymous objects, not a collection of `ProductRegistrationViewModelVM`.

Comment: Best guess is you want `vm =(from p in db.Products .....).Select(x => new ProductRegistrationViewModelV() { Name = x.Name, .... }).ToList();` although its unclear why you are adding a default instance using `vm.Add(new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM());`

Comment: @StephenMuecke vm.Add(new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM()); was automatically generated in the controllers index method.

Comment: The you probably want to delete that line. Its just adding a default instance to the collection - I assume you just want the objects from your quesy

Comment: And it needs to be `List<ProductRegistrationViewModelVM>  vm = new List<ProductRegistrationViewModelVM>();` - your query returns a collection, not a single `ProductRegistrationViewModelVM`. But you can delete that line of code and just use `List<ProductRegistrationViewModelVM>  vm = (from p in db.Product ....`

Answer (score 1):

The extension method `.Select` will returns a `IEnumerable<TResult>`, But you are trying to assign them to a business object of type `ProductRegistrationViewModelVM` such assignment is invalid, either you can change the type of `vm` to `var` or you have to make it as List if so the query will be like the following:

```
List<ProductRegistrationViewModelVM> vm =(from p in db.Products
                   join i in db.Images on p.ProductId equals i.Product_Id
                   join s in db.Specifications on p.ProductId equals s.Product_Id
                   select new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM
                   {
                       //Product
                       p.Name,
                       p.Produt_Code,
                       p.Description,
                       //Image
                       i.Image_Description,
                       i.Image_Name,
                       i.image1,
                       //Specifications
                       s.Sz_Measurement_Unit,
                       s.Size,
                       s.Wg_Measurement_Unit,
                       s.Weight,
                       s.Price_Set,
                       s.Price_Sold
                   }).ToList();
```

Now you can easily add another object of type `ProductRegistrationViewModelVM` to this since it a List of the same type. And you should do a small change in return as well. which will be like the following;

```
return View(vm); // No ToList is needed here since it is already a list
```

Comment: After implementing this code i am facing error.
"Cannot Initialize type  "ProductRegistrationViewModelVM" with a collection Initializer because it does not implement "Sysmtems.Collections.IEnumerable".

Answer (score 0):

You create a vm like this:

```
ProductRegistrationViewModelVM  vm = new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM();
```

Then you assign an IQueryable which returns anonymous types to it. That will not pass. Then you try and add a new instance of your view model to it and that will not work either:

```
vm.Add(new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM());
```

**Fix**

Try this instead:

```
var vm = ( from p in db.Products
         join i in db.Images on p.ProductId equals i.Product_Id
         join s in db.Specifications on p.ProductId equals s.Product_Id
         select new ProductRegistrationViewModelVM
         {
            //Product
            p.Name,
            p.Produt_Code,
            p.Description,
            //Image
            i.Image_Description,
            i.Image_Name,
            i.image1,
            //Specifications
            s.Sz_Measurement_Unit,
            s.Size,
            s.Wg_Measurement_Unit,
            s.Weight,
            s.Price_Set,
            s.Price_Sold
         } );

return View( vm.ToList() );
```

And make sure your view accepts a Model as `List<ProductRegistrationViewModelVM>`.

Comment: After implementing this code i am facing error.
"Cannot Initialize type  "ProductRegistrationViewModelVM" with a collection Initializer because it does not implement "Sysmtems.Collections.IEnumerable".

Comment: Did you use the exact code in the answer? Where do you get that error?

Comment: I go the error after  **//Product       p.Name,** after which i binded the properties to viewmodel properties explicitly to fix the error.